# React Error Handling - why does the app crash?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

*There is something basic that I am missing, but since I didn't find it myself, I overcame my embarrassment and decided to post it here...*

I expected the following code to render "Error", but not to crash afterwards. When running in chrome, however, it does crash, displaying the following:

[image: Crashing error]

### Why is that?

Here is the code:

### App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from 'components/Child';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {

    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo
    });
    console.log(`%c In App/componentDidCatch. error: ${error}, errorInfo:`, 'color: #222; background: #dfd');
    console.log(this.state.errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`%c In App/render. error: ${this.state.error}, errorInfo:`, 'color: #222; background: #dfd');
    console.log(this.state.errorInfo);
    if (this.state.error) {
      return (
        <div>
          Error
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    throw new Error('Child crashed!');
    return (
      <div>
        Child is here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would it render? It's not part of your return. Instead it's reaching the throw error before it gets there.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? [Your code works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/a849kv6b/1/).

Comment: @PaulRedmond Which component are you referring to?

Comment: @Tholle The code is working, but I didn't expect to get the chrome 'crash', only to see 'Error' on the browser... Isn't the idea that there is no crash? I see that in jsfiddle it doesn't crash.. My browser behaves differently when I run the code locally.

Comment: @Rahamin In child, you're calling the error in render but before the return, so it's doing exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: @PaulRedmond I am not asking why the child does not render. You are right, the 'return' in the child is not needed for the example. This  is not the point. The point, and my question, was - why does chrome crash?

Comment: @Tholle actually my problem is with a react native complex app that crashes on a genymotion emulator. I didn't undrrstand why it crashes, so I decided to write the simplest app on react and test it on my browser, thinking that the two apps will behave in a similar way, and they do... both crash and don't just display the error from the react component as I expected.

Comment: @Rahamin Alright, I see. I don't know what it could be, I'm afraid. I am not very good at React Native.

Comment: @Yossi Chrome is not crashing, CRA has this screen built in to highlight errors in dev mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you should render your Child component wrapped in App:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App>
        </Child>
      </App>
    );
  }
}
```

And App render method:

```
render() {
  console.log(`%c In App/render. error: ${this.state.error}, errorInfo:`, 'color: #222; background: #dfd');
  console.log(this.state.errorInfo);
  if (this.state.error) {
    return (
      <div>
        Error
      </div>
    );
  }

  return this.props.children
}
```

You should also consider changin the naming of your App component.

UPDATE (after discussion in comments).

You are using `react-create-app` which has build in overlay to signal errors.
Read that [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3627) for `react-create-app` to learn more.
Tip: you can close this overlay with x (look for it on your site).

Comment: Well, I didn't post the code that renders App... I thought that this is not needed for the example...

Comment: I am referencing App.js. You did post that.

Comment: One more thing baffles me. Didn't you set a debugger to catch all throws/errors? That way it won't work as you intend it to.

Comment: What do you mean in 'set a debugger'? I have an app created by create-react-app and I am running 'npm start'...

Comment: So here is your issue. `react-create-app` applies custom overlay when error happens. Read that [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3627) for `react-create-app`. You can close this overlay with `x` (look for it on the site).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be it! Can you update your answer so that I can accept it? Can you also look at my comment to Tholle above, regarding react-native? Any idea what is the expected behavior in react native? I am testing my app with genymotion, if this makes a difference.

Comment: Hey, I 've updated my answer.  About react-native - what is the error? I do not have enough info to elaborate on that ;/

Comment: The problem with react native is similar: the app crashes, while I expected componentDidCatch to handle it

Comment: Hey, I’ve updated the answer (bottom of it). I am looking into react-native issue.

Comment: So you managed to make it work in dev mode? From what I [read](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#in-app-errors-and-warnings) production build is not showing error/warning overlays

Comment: ComponentDidCatch seems to work with react-native 0.51.0 and react-navigation 1.5.6 (also with the newer versions mentioned in the link 3 comments above)